# Getting all posssible array index positions in an efficient way

Tags: java, arrays, performance, indexing

Hi i want to find a way to find all possible index positions in an arbitrary size and arbitrary number of dimension size array. For example:

```
int [][][] myArray = new int [2][3][2]
```

i would then want all possible array index positions so the output would be something like:

```
0,0,0
1,0,0
0,1,0
0,2,0
```

and so on, so basically all positions of the array, and a way which is somewhat more efficient than having lots and lots of embedded loops.

Comment: You've defined a 3-dimensional array and you're displaying a 2-dimensional array.  It's more subtle than what you're thinking of representing I think.  However, do you really need to display all positions, or do you need to enumerate all possible index combinations?

Comment: What do you want the input to be? A sequence of dimensions (2, 3, 2) or the actual array itself?

Comment: @Makoto sorry if its confusing thats what the output should be like, so thats not showing how the array should look like, its just showing all possible index combination. I just didnt show them all as it would be alot. But the output i just need the possible index combinations.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Hi i just need all the possible index combinations of an arbitrary array sorry if the output part was confusing

Comment: I don't see how you'd accomplish this *without* some form of nested iteration, though.  You could abstract it away and make it appear like there's only one or two loops happening, but it'd be however many dimensions you had you'd be looping over.

Comment: please define efficient! Anyway you have to pass through all of the data to display it

Comment: Hi, why would you create a three dimensional array? IMHO, this would be a waste of resources. Instead, if you identify max number of value (if ordered and gapless) of each array, you could just check for existence of the combination? Would this be faster? E.g. if you have 3 as max number and for sure you should have {0,0,0}, {1,1,0} {1,1,1} combinations.

Comment: @AlanLiang Do you have any comments on either of the answers? Is this close to what you're looking for?

Comment: @PaulBoddington yh the answers do what im asking for which is all possible index combinations, both answers are pretty good, but as im writing my code in scala, which processes java code, the first answer would be easier to convert  to scala, but thank you very much for your help :D much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multi-dimensional arrays are syntax sugar, they are physically located in single-dimension memory:

so, you can try something like that:

```
final int dim1 = 2;
final int dim2 = 3;
final int dim3 = 4;
final int[][][] myArray = new int[dim1][dim2][dim3];

for (long i = 0; i < ((long) dim1 * dim2 * dim3); i++) {
    long idx = i;
    final int i3 = (int) (idx % dim3);
    idx /= dim3;
    final int i2 = (int) (idx % dim2);
    idx /= dim2;
    final int i1 = (int) idx;
    System.out.println(i1 + "," + i2 + "," + i3);
}
```

note: this code uses `%` and `/` operators which are quite slow, but if your dimensions are power of 2, you can replace it with `&` and `>>>` which could run faster neither nested loops

another variant:

```
final int dim1 = 2;
final int dim2 = 3;
final int dim3 = 4;
final int[][][] myArray = new int[dim1][dim2][dim3];

int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 0;
int i3 = 0;
for (long i = 0; i < ((long) dim1 * dim2 * dim3); i++) {
    System.out.println(i1 + "," + i2 + "," + i3);
    i3++;
    if (i3 == dim3) {
        i3 = 0;
        i2++;
        if (i2 == dim2) {
            i2 = 0;
            i1++;
        }
    }
}
```

it could work faster, but it has branch inside loop, so its better to benchmark both variants

Answer (score 0):

I would favour an approach like this. The advantage of using a custom implementation of `List` like this is that you can represent all possible index combinations without having to store them all in memory simultaneously.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> indices = indices(2, 3);
    for (List<Integer> list : indices)
        System.out.println(list);
}

public static List<List<Integer>> indices(final int... dimensions) {
    int s = 1;
    for (int a : dimensions)
       s *= a;
    final int size = s;
    return new AbstractList<List<Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return size;
        }
        @Override
        public List<Integer> get(int index) {
            if (index < 0 || index >= size)
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int d : dimensions) {
                temp.add(index % d);
                index /= d;
            }
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(temp);
        }
    };
}
```